# Too Many )'s when matching

Tags: c#, regex

I have written the following simple regular expression to match a pattern.

It has the following conditions:

1. It must contain the word Supplier at the beginning of the sentence
2. The word Supplier must be followed by a space
3. The space must be followed by a 3 or 4 digit number

My RegEx looks like this:

```
(Supplier )([0-9]{3,4})
```

When I run the following against it and the input has '(' or ')' in it, I receive the error `Too Many )'s`.

```
Regex.IsMatch("(Supplier )([0-9]{3,4})", "Supplier 2000 (detail)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Is anybody able to verify my syntax, offer any advice or provide an alternative expression for use in my case?

Comment: what does your regex look like?

Comment: My RegEx is (Supplier )([0-9]{3,4}) with text Supplier 2000 (detail)

Comment: MSDN is wonderful place [Regex.IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx) have arguments in different order than you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have your `input` and your `pattern` backwards.

From the [`Regex.IsMatch` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktzf2d23.aspx):

```
public static bool IsMatch(
    string input,
    string pattern,
    RegexOptions options
)
```